# Counting words in a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I am learning C++ on my own. I have written this program to count the number of words in a string. I know it's not the best way to do this, but this was what I could think of.

I am using spaces to count the number of words. Here is the problem.

```
countWords("");   // ok, 'x.empty()' identifies it as an empty string.
countWords("  "); // 'x.empty()' fails, function returns 1.
```

p.s I want this program to not count symbols like, "!","?" as words. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int countWords(std::string x);

int main() {
    std::cout << countWords("Hello world!");
}

int countWords(std::string x) {
    if(x.empty()) return 0; // if the string is empty
    int Num = 1;              

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        // if there is a space in the start
        if(x[0] == ' ') continue;

        // second condition makes sure that i don't count 2 spaces as 2 words
        else if(x[i] == ' ' && x[i - 1] != ' ') Num++;
    }
    return Num;
}
```

Comment: First, the `empty` check is redundant. Second go through what happens with `" 123 456 789"` in your head. For brevity, a simple call to `std::unique`, followed by `std::count`ing the spaces should work. For one pass, `std::find`ing the next space and `std::find_if_not`ing the next non-space repeatedly works as well.

Comment: You set `Num` to 1 before you begin the loop, so in your second example the code has to return `1`

`x.empty()` has to return false in the second case as well, as your string is not empty (it contains one space)

Comment: @UnholySheepm, I know that. But if I set Num to zero, then I can't get the desired results.

Comment: @Blastfurnace No, see 1st if condition. when 1st is true, 2nd never runs. +1 for your help btw.

Comment: @user3834119 I assume you mean that you get 1 less than you were expecting, in which case you could add another test statement: `x[i]=='\0'` as zero termination is the end of a string

Comment: @Blastfurnace why should it do that? `x[i]==' '` should be evaluated first and if that is `false` then the other one won't be evaluated at all. It may not be a great solution, but it should work

Comment: @UnholySheep: You are right and I am very wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Blastfurnace when x[0] is not a space, then even second condition won't be true. How awesome is that?

Comment: @user3834119 You have changed the question after getting several answers. People will most likely not change their answers to adapt to the new definition of the question (with "!" and "?" not counting as words). To decrease confusion and increase your chance of getting good answers, please post a separate question about that.

Comment: @anatolyg Thank you for the suggestion. Next time, i will try to explain things more while asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can be reduced to this:

```
int countWords(std::string x) {

    int Num = 0;      
    char prev = ' ';

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {

        if(x[i] != ' ' && prev == ' ') Num++;

        prev = x[i];
    }
    return Num;
}
```

Here is a [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a81f14b04ccad99b)

Edit: To follow up comment:

Here is a simple way to replace other characters with `' '`, thought there might be a build method for this:

```
void replace(std::string &s, char replacer, std::set<char> &replacies)
{
    for (int i=0; i < s.size(); i++)
        if (replacies.count(s[i])) s[i] = replacer;

}
```

[demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de273dd07ec70584)

Comment: +1 for good coding. I want the program to work for symbols like, "?","!", these symbols shouldn't be counted as words. Can you suggest a way?

Comment: @user3834119, so you basically want `"?","!"..` to be treated like spaces are treated now, perhaps you can just replace those characters with spaces.

Comment: @Ajavall Yes. And how do you do that(replace them with spaces)?

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is insufficient. It will fail when applied with:

- Leading spaces
- Trailing spaces
- Only spaces
- Other forms of whitespace

You need to rethink how your algorithm should work as you simply need a more sophisticated method to cover all the use cases.

Or you could avoid reinventing the wheel and use what the *standard library* already provides, e.g.:

```
int countWords(const std::string& s) {
    std::istringstream iss{s};
    return std::distance(std::istream_iterator<std::string>{iss},
                         std::istream_iterator<std::string>{});
}
```

Here [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) is used to tokenize the string, and [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is used to get the number of tokens extracted.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your answer is that you are counting the number of words after which there is a ' ' sign. I believe you start with Num = 1 because you won't be counting the last word. Hovewer that only occurs when the string youre analysing does not end with ' '. Otherwise you will have 1 more word counted. The easiest way to fix this is to add

```
if(x.back() == ' ')
    Num--;
```

right before returning the answer.

Comment: `x[x.size() - 1]` is just `x.back()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best using string stream:

```
int Count(const std::string &string)
{
  stringstream ss(string);
  char cmd[256] = {0};
  int Words = 0;
  while(true)
  {
    ss >> cmd;
    if(!ss)
        break;
    Words++;
  }
  return Words;
```

**Input:** " Hello my  dear    friend "
**Output:** 4

It will not fail even if appiled with:

- Leading spaces
- Trailing spaces
- Only spaces
- Other forms of whitespace

Comment: "Output: 4", where's the input?

Comment: @Quest Try this. std::stringstream ss("what are you talking about ?");

Output: 6

Comment: @user3834119: And is the output not supposed to be 6? :O

Comment: @Silnik We are counting words here, not characters. There are 5 words in that sentence.
Even when you try this, "Hello my dear friend ." (4 words)
Output: 5

Comment: @user3834119: Then you have not defined what a word is. Everyone here will expect a word to be a string of chars without spaces surrounded by spaces. Then according to your definition is any of the: "!!!", "I", "potato!" a word? You have not given enought information in the question.

Comment: @Silnik We all know what word is, you can think of it like counting number of words in a sentence. Now if there is a sentence, "My name is michael." Anyone can tell, there are 4 words. Ofcourse, "!" or ".",is not a word, it is just a chracter.
p.s "potato!" is a word.

Comment: @user3834119: if we all knew what a word is all the answers would not be interpreting "words" in the definition that I gave you. 'I' is a single character, is it not a word? You have no idea what you are asking for. Is then "saldnakdjvbkzdjbvkzxcz';.;';asknla" a word? I never heard of such, a word, but for sure it is not a character. You either give the exact definition of a "word" or you stick to the most obvious one, which is definietly not yours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57607/discussion-between-user3834119-and-silnik).

Comment: @user3834119 All the answers here are counting "Hey !" as 2 words... Shouldn't it be "Hey!"? (without space)

Comment: @Quest  But we have to write the program, for every case. It should work when user enetrs, "HEY !". And we can't treat symbols as words. "!" is not a word. Please refer to my solution in answers.

Comment: @Quest Well, I thought, it would be obvious, we don't treat symbols as words usually. Anyways, next time I would keep your suggestion in mind.

Answer (score 1):

So I tried on my own, after reading some useful comments. Here is my solution. I have checked my program for worst case scenario. If any of you, can find any cases for which this program doesn't work, let me know, so that I can work and improve it.

And just to be clear, we don't want symbols like, "," , "!" , "?", "." , "\n" to be counted as words. But obviously, "I" should be counted as word, as we consider it in the language. I have made sure of all this by replacing them with spaces. Let me know if I missed something.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

void replace(std::string& str, char x, char y);
int countWords(std::string x);

int main(){
std::cout<<countWords(" \n \t Hello, world ! ");
}

void replace(std::string& str, char x, char y){
for(unsigned int i=0;i<str.size();i++){
    if(str[i]==x) str[i]=y;
}
}

int countWords(std::string x){

replace(x,',',' ');
replace(x,'.',' ');
replace(x,'!',' ');
replace(x,'?',' ');
replace(x,'(',' ');
replace(x,')',' ');
replace(x,'\n',' ');
replace(x,'\t',' ');
replace(x,'"',' ');

if(x.empty()) return 0;
int Num=1;

for(unsigned int i=1;i<x.size();i++){
    if(x[i]==' ' && x[i-1]!=' ') Num++;
}
if(x.back() == ' ') Num--;
return Num;
}
```

Comment: What about '? In function replace, const qualifier have no reason. And function countWords is wastefully slow

Comment: @Quest Thanks for your suggestion. It works when you use "?". And if you can suggest a way to make function fast, that would be appreciated.

Comment: you should try Blastfurnace s answer and add more switch cases

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and fast on my machine. It iterates over the string, using a `bool` to track 
whether it's inside a word or not, and whitespace characters as word delimiters. I tested with the `isspace()` library function but this `switch` statement was slightly faster.

```
int countwords(const std::string &str)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool in_word = false;
    for (char ch : str) {
        switch (ch) {
        case '\t': case '\n': case '\v': case '\f': case '\r': case ' ':
            in_word = false;
            break;
        default:
            if (!in_word) {
                in_word = true;
                ++count;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

This is easy to extend or modify for different word delimiters. Here is a version that considers any non-alphabetical character as a delimiter. Changing the `!isalpha()` call to `isspace()` will give the same results as the code above.

```
int countwords(const std::string &str)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool in_word = false;
    for (char ch : str) {
        if (!isalpha(ch)) { // non-alpha chars are word delimiters
            in_word = false;
        } else if (!in_word) {
            in_word = true;
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int countwords(std::string x)
{
    int i, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
        if (x[i] == ' ')
            count++; //just count empty spaces

    count++; //count++ is same as count+1,so there will be count+1 words in string
    if (x.size() == 0)
        count = 0;
    return count;
}
```

Comment: This is not true - according to your solution countWords("Hello_____world!") = 5, where _ is ' ' but in the comments writing 4 spaces in a row gets deleted.

Comment: yes I mentioned that there is only 1 empty space as separator,but u can transform those 4 empty spaces into one without a problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the code

```
int Num;
if(x[0] == ' ') Num = 0;
else Num = 1;
```

this would eliminate the count of a blank in the start of the string

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int countWords(std::string x);

int main() {
    std::cout << countWords("Hello world!");
}

int countWords(std::string x) {
    if(x.empty()) return 0; // if the string is empty

    int Num;
    if(x[0] == ' ') Num = 0;
    else Num = 1;


    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
        // if there is a space in the start
        if(x[0] == ' ') continue;

        // second condition makes sure that i don't count 2 spaces as 2 words
        else if(x[i] == ' ' && x[i - 1] != ' ') Num++;
    }
    return Num;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. In your case countWords("Hello  ") = 2